# How can I run my Python projects with imports of my own codes?

Tags: python, webassembly, pyodide

I want to run a game project of my own (text interface only) using pyodide.
But I can't deal very well with the nested imports of my game, pyodide always reports the error " No module called  found.

I will give an example in a smaller project that gives the same error.

display.py

```
import hello

def main():
    hello.talk_hello()
main()
```

hello.py

```
def talk_hello():
    print("Hello!")
```

script running pyodide

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      async function main() {
        let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
        return pyodide;
      }
      let pyodideReadyPromise = main();
      
      // Pyodide - carregar arquivos e executar chamada
      async function evaluatePython() {
        let pyodide = await pyodideReadyPromise;
        try {
          let python_code = (await (await fetch('display.py')).text());
          await pyodide.runPythonAsync(python_code)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
      evaluatePython();
    </script>
```

Pyodide error

PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/lib/python311.zip/_pyodide/_base.py", line 571, in eval_code_async
await CodeRunner(
File "/lib/python311.zip/_pyodide/_base.py", line 394, in run_async
coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'

I expect all imports, whether official or part of my file, to be loaded into pyodide.
Because it will only fetch the file that I directly insert.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate, but let me know if the duplicate doesn't address your question

Answer (score -1):

Not the BEST way to fix this, but for a small project you can indicate *where* the module that you've written lives by setting the current directory to it, and *then* try to import. It would look something like:

```
import os
os.chdir(r"path\to\the\folder\containing\your\.pyfiles")

import hello
hello.talk_hello()
```

Additionally, if you want to load in everything and not have to call the `hello` module, you could write it as:

```
import os
os.chdir(r"path\to\the\folder\containing\your\.pyfiles")

from hello import *
talk_hello()
```

Comment: This might or might not work depending on your IDE, but this absolutely does work if you're in a live/CMD instance

Comment: Why would your IDE matter? Perhaps more importantly, the OP is running Pyodide, which is a pretty exotic runtime so that would probably be where the problem results from. For example, *it doesn't have access to your filesystem*.

Answer (score -1):

you need add `hello.py` to a package :
Create a new folder(hello_package) and create a file named `__init__.py` inside it and Put "hello.py" in it
and then write import  like this

in display.py:

```
from .hello_package import hello

def main():
    hello.talk_hello()
```

Comment: why would putting it in a package solve anything?

Comment: As juanapa is hinting... you are thinking of Python run on a system with access to the local files. (See  juanapa's great comments to Sand's answer.)  This question is about pyodide based stuff running in a browser. And even if this post had been about typical Python, you'd still be complicating things beyond what is necessary, because  you don't need to be that fancy to do import with typical Python. There's no need for adding `__init__.py` to do import. The way the OP has the two files and import statement in the original post would work with full, typical Python.